# Loading images from a folder [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently experiencing a problem with my program. I want to create a photo gallery for my girlfriend which she can install on her computer. I want to import images from a folder on Form load and display them in a PictureBox.

When I load the Form I get a big red 'X' that fills the box. Looks like the drawing.bitmap ErrorImage. What could be the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    Private Sub Pigge_Gallary_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Pics\Bears")
    If directory.Exists Then
        Dim jpgFiles() As IO.FileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg")
        For Each jpgFile As IO.FileInfo In jpgFiles
            If jpgFile.Exists Then
                Dim image = Drawing.Image.FromFile(jpgFile.FullName)
                Using image
                    PicPig.Image = image
                End Using
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Iterating through the list like this would only show you the last image anyways, so the whole loop is pointless. Furthermore you are disposing the image immediately after loading it, as Chase Rocker pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you exit the `Using` block, you're losing the image reference.

Try changing

```
PicPig.Image = image
```

to

```
PicPig.Image = image.clone
```

or just set it to the image from the file:

```
PicPig.Image = Drawing.Image.FromFile(jpgFile.FullName)
```

Also, because you're doing it in a For loop, it's just going to replace the picturebox image as it loops. When it finishes the loop, the picturebox will only be displaying the last image.